# When hovering over <ul> I want another <ul> to show up

Tags: html, css, hover

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/5153/

Hello, I am trying to make the li tags inside `#hovershow` show up when I mouse-over `.navbar` by using `:hover` together with `display:none`

this isn't working but when I manually change the `display:none` to `display:table-row` it does.

Comment: Are you willing to use javascript?

Comment: @arandompenguin why would you want to use javascript?

Comment: @3rror404 Whoops, didn't read the question correctly, my mistake.

Comment: @arandompenguin I've been thinking about it, but I prefer this. Got it working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this css:

```
.navbar:hover + .hovershow {
    display: table-row;
}
```

to:

```
.navbar:hover .hovershow {
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/5155/)

Comment: +1 And since there's no table displayed element in the markup, I'd suggest to use `display: block;` instead of `display: table-row;`.

Comment: Thank you! I've got it working. I always thought that if you'd want another element to respond to a css hover you would have to use a +

Comment: Good point Hashem. Edited the answer to take your suggestion into account.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
.navbar:hover + .hovershow {
    display: table-row;
}
```

to this:

```
.navbar li:hover > .hovershow {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/5156/)